# bootstrap mobile first grid inline full screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to build a mobile first web page and so I am testing Bootstrap grid system as this seemed the easy way forward, but I am having trouble getting the grid to go full length on a mobile iphone 6s (same with all screen sizes within this range).
I have a test script with 6 columns to be displayed inline across the screen.

If I use the following col-xs the grid lines up inline but there is a large amount of white space to the right. Code and screen shot shown below.

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="border:solid; padding: 5px;">test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="border:solid; padding: 5px;">test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="border:solid; padding: 5px;">test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="border:solid; padding: 5px;">test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="border:solid; padding: 5px;">test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="border:solid; padding: 5px;">test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

If I change the code to col-sm I get the grid stacked up as shown below screen shot

[image]

What is the best approach to get these boxes lined up side by side across the whole screen. Should I use padding or width % CSS on each box or is there a better approach to this than Bootstrap

Comment: sm and xs are the parameters which specify when the cols break up, as sm breaks up early you see every col beneath each other

Comment: I understand the sm and xs make the column stack up on screen size but I thought bootstrap was made for mobile first applications so xs would make the boxes line up across the screen, I expect i will use css to do this. at present i am dropping bootstrap for pure css grid

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to bootstrap i recomend you start with boostrap v4 which has solved this problem.

just take a look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works

here is an example. every column automatically become 33.33% of entire screen width

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

If you insist on using bootstrap v3, use can do something like this:

```css
.row-eq-height {
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -webkit-flex;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
            }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container ">
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="border:solid; padding: 5px;">test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="border:solid; padding: 5px;">test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="border:solid; padding: 5px;">test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="border:solid; padding: 5px;">test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="border:solid; padding: 5px;">test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="border:solid; padding: 5px;">test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The example above was using bootstrap 4.3.1